# How do I add links to variants of products in a product card (displayed on landing page and collections page) on Shopify?

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

On the landing page and collections page, below each product, I want the color variants to link to the variant with the color selected e.g. if I click on the red color, it takes me to the product page with the red variant selected. I managed to add the color variants but I don't know how to link them to the variants. The products also have sizes as they are clothes, so I want the XS size to be selected by default.

When the red variant is clicked, takes to the product page with variants with XS and Red selected.
When the black variant is clicked, takes to the product page with variants XS and Black selected. 
When the black variant is clicked, takes to the product page with variants XS and White selected.

How do I dynamically add a link that redirects to the product page with XS + color clicked?

[image: Screenshot from Crop Shop Boutique]

Source: https://cropshopboutique.com/

The code I have for the colors so far are:

**color-option-row.liquid**

```
<div class="product-option-row flex justify-between flex-column flex-row-ns tc tl-ns mb4">
  <div class="option-values">
    {% for value in option.values %}
      {% assign radio_id = 'option-' | append: option_name | append: '-' | append: value | handleize %}

<a href="{{ product.url }}?variant={{ variant.id }}">
  <label for="{{ radio_id }}">
    {% if force_colors == true %}
      {% include 'option-color' with color: value %}
    {% else %}
      {{ value }}
    {% endif %}
  </label>
</a>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

**color-variant-hover.liquid**

```
{% assign has_multiple_variants = false %}
{% if product.variants.size > 1 %}
  {% assign has_multiple_variants = true %}
{% endif %}

{% assign has_multiple_options = false %}
{% if product.options.size > 1 %}
  {% assign has_multiple_options = true %}
{% endif %}

{% assign has_selected_variant = false %}
{% if product.selected_variant != nil %}
  {% assign has_selected_variant = true %}
{% endif %}

{% if has_multiple_variants %}
  {% include 'get-variants-with-quantity-json' with product: product %}
{% endif %}

{% assign can_add_to_cart = false %}
{% if has_selected_variant and product.selected_variant.available %}
  {% assign can_add_to_cart = true %}
{% elsif has_multiple_variants == false and product.available %}
  {% assign can_add_to_cart = true %}
{% endif %}

  {% if has_multiple_options or has_multiple_variants %}
    {% for option in product.options_with_values %}
      {% assign option_name = 'option' | append: option.position %}

      {% assign selected = false %}
      {% if has_selected_variant %}
        {% assign selected = product.selected_variant[option_name] %}
      {% endif %}

      {% assign default_variant = product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}

      {% if option.name == 'Color' %}
      <div class="option-colors">
        {% include 'color-option-row' with option: option, option_name: option_name, selected: selected, force_colors: true %}
      </div>

      {% elsif option.name == 'Pattern' %}
      <div class="option-patterns">
        {% include 'color-option-row' with option: option, option_name: option_name, selected: selected, force_colors: true %}
      </div>

      {% else %}
      <div class="dn">
        {% include 'color-option-row' with option: option, option_name: option_name, type: 'select', selected: selected %}
      </div>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}

  <input class="js-variant-id" type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ default_variant.id }}">
```

**featured-products.liquid**

```
<div class="product-card fl w-50 w-25-l mb3 ph1 ph3-m ph3-l">
  {% include 'product-card' %}
  {% include 'color-variant-hover' %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update your **color-option-row.liquid** to the following:

```
<div class="product-option-row flex justify-between flex-column flex-row-ns tc tl-ns mb4">
  <div class="option-values">
    {% for value in option.values %}
      {% assign radio_id = 'option-' | append: option_name | append: '-' | append: value | handleize %}

{%- for variant in product.variants -%}
  {%- if variant.title contains value -%}
    {%- assign productColorOptionURL = product.url | append: "?variant=" | append: variant.id -%}
    {%- break -%}
  {%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}

<a href="{{ productColorOptionURL }}">
  <label for="{{ radio_id }}">
    {% if force_colors == true %}
      {% include 'option-color' with color: value %}
    {% else %}
      {{ value }}
    {% endif %}
  </label>
</a>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work for me - the featured product images on the home page
https://risinglotusclothing.myshopify.com/

Comment: How did you try that? I see that if you open this link with the `variant` query parameter option added to the end of the URL, it opens the black variant option pre-selected: https://risinglotusclothing.myshopify.com/products/macrame-leggings?variant=33691115683884 i

Comment: I added this below the product card
      <div class="option-colors">
        {% include 'color-option-row' with option: option, option_name: option_name, selected: selected, force_colors: true %}
      </div>

Comment: where color-option-row contains

    {% for value in option.values %}
      {% assign radio_id = 'option-' | append: option_name | append: '-' | append: value | handleize %}

      <a href="{{ product.url }}/variant?={{ variant.id }}">
        <label for="{{ radio_id }}">
          {% if force_colors == true %}
            {% include 'option-color' with color: value %}
          {% else %}
            {{ value }}
          {% endif %}
        </label>
      </a>
    {% endfor %}

Comment: 1. I don't see any color options displayed on the home page.
2. You place the `?` sign incorrectly, it shout be `?variant={{ variant.id }}`, not `/variant?={{ variant.id }}`

Comment: I just added this code to the featured products section but it doesn't work :(  You can see the colors but the links don't work

`<a href="{{ product.url }}?variant={{ variant.id }}">`
 `<label for="{{ radio_id }}">`
    `{% if force_colors == true %}`
      `{% include 'option-color' with color: value %}`
    `{% else %}`
     ` {{ value }}`
   ` {% endif %}`
  `</label>`
`</a>`

Is there a way I can send you my code?

Comment: I just edited the post again so you can see all the codes I used for this. I made it visible on the site again as well so you could check now. Thank you so much for taking your time to explain it to me

Comment: I see the issue now. There are no variant ID information available in the `color-option-row.liquid` snippet. See the updated answer.